# Custom return type for class function based on how it was initialized

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

Is it possible or makes sense to `@overload` the return type `Hashable` of a `CLASS.function() -> Hashable:` based on how the relevant `self.obj` was initialized?

```
from typing import Hashable, overload

class CLASS:

    obj = None
    obj_type = Hashable

    def __init__(self, INPUT: Hashable) -> None:
        self.obj = INPUT
        # Specifying the type
        self.obj_type = type(self.obj)
        # This does not work?
        if self.obj_type == int:
            @overload
            def returner() -> int: ...

    def returner() -> Hashable:
        return self.obj
```

If I pass a value of a certain type to the constructor, then the type of the value returned is unambiguous.

Comment: Are you just trying to make the class _generic_, e.g. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=ef5a7ac4f2459f0ff113f59a50d37c96?

Comment: My problem was that in another function `f` I was expecting an obvious return type of `int` based on how I initialize the `CLASS` object. And the returned value I pass on, so `f` could easily satisfy a concrete return type `int`, but `pyright` did not infer the return type and so it did not allow me to specify the concrete return type `int` for `f`, which is however needed. Therefore I tried to make it more concrete...

Comment: But what you suggested looks like I can determine upon initialization what the return type should be and just need to figure out what I input to the constructor at that point outside of the class definition, I think that should make sense. I am not familiar with this topic, so I will now look into this `Generic` stuff..

Comment: With what I suggested above, something like `i: int = Class(123).returner()` would also be valid. It's unclear what you'd previously tried that pyright didn't like, but what you've posted doesn't make any sense.